# Не меняется значения в P по нажатию

Tags: javascript

Works on any device anyware

```js
var d = document;
  function change_txt(a) {
    if (a.className == "class1") {
       a.className = "class2";
       d.getElementById(p.className = "why_tank_app_text_in").innerHTML = "SAVE TIME";
    }
    else {
       a.className = "class1";
       d.getElementById(p.className = "why_tank_app_text_in").innerHTML = "& GAIN AGILITY";
    }
}
```

```html
<p class="why_tank_app_text_in">Works on any device anyware</p>
<li><a href="#" onClick="change_txt(this)" class="class1">1</a></li>
```

Comment: что за конструкция внутри `getElementById` у вас?

Comment: Из параграфа забираю Class why_tank_app_text_in

Comment: @AlexanderVardanyan, `id` и `class` - это кагбэ "немножко" разные вещи...

Answer (score 0):

Вот так будет меняться...

```js
var d = document, 
    p = d.querySelector('.why_tank_app_text_in');  // или d.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]; или d.getElementsByClassName('why_tank_app_text_in')[0]; 
function change_txt(a) {
  if (a.className == "class1") {
    a.className = "class2";
    p.innerHTML = "SAVE TIME";
  } else {
    a.className = "class1";
    p.innerHTML = "& GAIN AGILITY";
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="why_tank_app_text_in">Works on any device anyware</p>
<li><a href="#" onClick="change_txt(this)" class="class1">1</a></li>
```

Код странный, конечно...